# Any way to have a pagination or search query for the dynamic list of fonts?

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-font-api

The whole list consists of almost 1mb of the data. I want to implement an autocomplete for selecting Google Fonts. I have already included `fields` param (to get only a needed data). Is it possible to use search query for this endpoint?

Talking about this one:
https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=YOUR-API-KEY

Answer (score 1):

I found out you can use parameters with api here https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api

If you only want families (font names) and subsets (cyrilic, latin etc.) you can use "fileds" parameter with **items.family,items.subsets** (items.variants - this would add avaliable weights and styles with another 100 kB)

This will send you just 150 kB, which is better than 1 MB.

You can filter these parameters by your own preferences and then use this api https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2

Which is how google do it on their font page https://fonts.google.com/

With this: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,900

You will get Roboto font regular 900 and italic 400 (400 is default font weight)

With this: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,900;1,700

You will get Roboto font regular 900 and italic 700.

You can parse these files then and get only your desired subset.

For your previews you can use the same url with some extra parameters so you can download only the characters you will use: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,900;1,700&subset=latin-ext&display=block&text=%20,.ABabdefghiklmnorstuw